# Double integration in R

Tags: r

I have to find a double integral as a function of $ \alpha, \beta $ and $ \gamma $.

[image]

> f(a,b,c) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y1} \gamma(a+b+c)/\gamma(a)/\gamma(b)/\gamma(c) * y1^(a+1) * y2^(b-1) * (1-y1-y2)^(c-1) dy_2 dy_1

The output of this double integral should be an R function that takes three arguments a, b and c. How can I implement this in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913603/calculating-double-integrals-in-r-quickly?rq=1 Didn't even have to search, this should have appeared when you typed in that title and warned you not to make this question

Comment: rawr/ I don't think your criticism is reasonable. My question is different from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of integration is the triangle with vertices (0,0), (0,1) and (1,0). The `SimplicialCubature` package is the way to use for such a domain.

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
K <- gamma(a+b+c)/gamma(a)/gamma(b)/gamma(c)
f <- function(x){
  K * x[1]^(a+1)*x[2]^(b-1)*(1-x[1]-x[2])^(c-1)
}
S <- cbind(c(0,0),c(0,1),c(1,0)) # domain of integration (triangle)
```

---

```
> library(SimplicialCubature)
> adaptIntegrateSimplex(f, S)
$integral
[1] 0.04761905

$estAbsError
[1] 4.761905e-14

$functionEvaluations
[1] 32

$returnCode
[1] 0

$message
[1] "OK"
```

Answer (score -1):

In the past, I've used the `cubature` package. It has worked for me in cases similar to yours, and I'm sure you can use it!

Comment: I tried 'cubature' but it does not seem to allow non-constant interval of integration