# Numerical Triple Integration in R

Tags: r, integral, numerical-integration

Is it possible to do triple integration in R without using the cubature package?

[based on the answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189512/double-integral-in-r)

```
InnerFunc = function(x) { x + 0.805 }
InnerIntegral = function(y) { sapply(y, 
    function(z) { integrate(InnerFunc, 15, z)$value }) }
integrate(InnerIntegral , 15, 50)
16826.4 with absolute error < 1.9e-10
```

For example, to code [this triple integral](https://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/255trip/255trip.html):

[image]

I tried

```
InnerMostFunc = function(v) { v + y^2 }
InnerMostIntegral = function(w) { sapply(w, 
   function(x) { integrate(InnerMostFunc, 1, 2)$value }) }
InnerIntegral = function(y) { sapply(y, 
   function(z){integrate(InnerMostIntegral, 1, 2)$value }) }
integrate(InnerIntegral, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I am having trouble reading what triple integral you are trying to compute. Can you provide the formula? Perhaps using an image of the formula like in the post that you cited.

Comment: @G5W I tried to clean it up better!

Comment: A triple integral requires three variables (and three separate ranges). Your integrations only have one variable, although I'm guessing you are intending to integrate over a square cube.

Comment: So you cannot expect R to deliver that symbolic result, but you could get a result if you specified a value for `k`.

Comment: @42 - ah yes I was trying to integrate over a square cube. I keep finding examples with repeated ranges though (like the most recent one I added). You really can't do a triple integral with repeated ranges?

Comment: You would need to specify the ranges in some 3d structure and use them to specify the inner function calls to integrate. The new version of the question is going to require a function capable of dealing with partial derivatives and I don't think that `integrate is there yet. Could be wrong.... discarding my draft answer since new version too complex for my strategy.

Comment: @42 so there is essentially no way for me to do triple integration using the the model I found in the other post?

Comment: @G52 I've tried your solution from the other post and it works for cube functions?

Comment: integrate(function(z) {
   sapply(z, function(z){
        integrate(function(y) {
                sapply(y, function(y) {
        integrate(function(x) myfun(x,y,z), llim, ulim)$value
         })
        }, llim, ulim)$value
    })
}, llim, ulim)

Comment: @GW5 it's basically integrating where y and z is kept as a constant via in the inner function, and then y is applied as a variable in the first outer function keeping only z as constant and it hits the outer application loop which applies the last layer

Comment: I think that what you said is right. It will work for triple integral where  the inner function has only one variable, but the limits depend on the others.   Would it be helpful if I wrote up an example as an answer?

Comment: @G5W it would of great help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Further down is the extension of the cited [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43194274/4752675) that was asked for in the comments.  But this top part will show how to compute the integral given in the updated post.

[image: Triple Integral]

This is harder to write than the type of integral below, because the functions must be completely nested. You can't separate them out as in the second example, so the single expression is rather long and hard to read.  Here is the code to compute the requested integral.

```
integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { 
    integrate(Vectorize(function(y) { 
        integrate(function(z) { x^2 + y*z }, 1, 2)$value }), 1,2)$value }), 0,1)
2.583333 with absolute error < 2.9e-14
```

Notice that it computes the correct answer 31/12. The cited source of the integral incorrectly gives the answer as 31/4.

**Extension of referenced previous post**

Here is an example of extending the process from the previous post to a triple integral.   The example that I will compute is simple to do analytically, so we can check that we are getting the correct answer. I will use:

[image: Triple Integral]

In order to make it easier to follow,  I am breaking the code up into several steps.

```
InnerFunc = function(x) { x + 1 }
InnerIntegral = Vectorize(function(y) { integrate(InnerFunc, 0, y)$value})
Integral2     = Vectorize(function(z) { integrate(InnerIntegral , 0, z)$value})
(Tripleintegral = integrate(Integral2 , 0, 4))
21.33333 with absolute error < 2.4e-13
```

This extends the previous example,  but does *not* cover the type of integral in the new statement of the problem.

Comment: Bravo! And with no changes of variables. I didn't think that was possible in such a compact form. But it did need explicit ranges.

Comment: Color me "puzzled". If the upper limit of the innermost integral had been 5, you wouldn't needed to have changed anything?

Answer (score 3):

For such an integral, the `cubature` package is the way to go.

```
> library(cubature)
> hcubature(function(v) v[1]^2+v[2]*v[3], c(0,1,1), c(1,2,2))
$integral
[1] 2.583333
```