# Why is my double integral is R not working

Tags: r, integral

I folloed this post here [double integral in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189512/double-integral-in-r) and switched the function and limits to match below but it's not working.

[image]

```
InnerFunc = function(x) { x + (y^2) }
InnerIntegral = function(z) { sapply(y, 
        function(z) { integrate(InnerFunc, 0, 2)$value }) }
integrate(InnerIntegral, 0, 1)
```

I get this error:

Error in integrate(InnerFunc, 0, 2) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are all out of wack. This should do what you want

```
InnerFunc <- function(x, y) { x + (y^2) }
InnerIntegral <- function(y) { sapply(y, 
  function(z) { integrate(InnerFunc, 0, 2, y=z)$value }) }
integrate(InnerIntegral, 0, 1)
# 2.666667 with absolute error < 3e-14
```

Notice how `InnerFunc` is now a function of both `x` and `y`. Also notice how we apply over the vector passed to `InnerIntegral` via the `y` parameter (rather than ignoring the `z` value passed in). We also pass in the current value of `y` to `InnerFunc`.

Although you typed

```
InnerFunc <- function(x, y) { x + (y^2) }
```

the math you drew looks should really result in

```
InnerFunc <- function(x, y) { x * (y^2) }
```

so I'm not sure what you were really after.

Comment: hi so the answer should be .6666667, see here https://www.symbolab.com/solver/double-integrals-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%7Dxy%5E%7B2%7D%20dxdy

Comment: I already mentioned in the answer that in your code you put `x + (y^2)` but if you meant `x * (y^2)` then you'd get .666 as expected.