# Triple integration using R when each inner integral depends on the others

Tags: r, integral

My question is similar to "[double integral in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189512/double-integral-in-r).", but in my case, I want to do a triple integration where each limit depends on the outer integral.

I wnat to calculate

[image]

How do I define the inner dependencies?

Comment: Question to the flagging team: Does this question really follow the category "too broad"? I agree that OP should have presented what he or she had tried to do, but The question seems clear: given a function f:R->R calculate the triple integral of the above form. Am I missing something about "too broad" category?

Comment: Agreed with @storaged. RGG: to evaluate this integral, one can split the domain of integration into simplices and integrate with the SimplicialCubature package. But I need the answer space to develop...

Comment: @storaged I voted to reopen. I'd like to post an answer. Please vote to reopen if you agree.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent ...it's embarassing, but I don't know how to vote for the reopening...

Comment: See https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/integralPolyhedron.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that basing on the suggestion from the post you have attached the key is to add the `Vectorize` function and we come up with something like this:

```
# Example function 
phi <- function(t){t}

integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { 
  integrate(Vectorize(function(y) { 
    integrate(function(z) { 
      phi(x)*phi(y)*phi(z)   ## function you want to calculate
    }, -10, 6-x-y)$value     ## 2nd level interval
   }), -5, 3-x)$value        ## 1st level interval
}), -5,4)                    ## top interval

# 16480.2 with absolute error < 1.8e-10
```

the above approach is quite general, so you can test on other functions. (The answer is the same as provided by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%20-5%20to%204%20integral%20from%20-5%20to%20(3-x)%20integral%20from%20-10%20to%20(6%20-%20x%20-%20y)%20of%20z%20*%20y%20*%20x%20%20dz%20dy%20%20dx))

Comment: I tried that and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks

Comment: If you have such possibility, please accept the answer