# Double integration with a differentiation inside in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration, differentiation

I need to integrate the following function where there is a differentiation term inside. Unfortunately, that term is not easily differentiable.

Is this possible to do something like numerical integration to evaluate this in R?

[image: Function to integrate]
You can assume 30,50,0.5,1,50,30 for l, tau, a, b, F and P respectively.

UPDATE: What I tried

```
InnerFunc4 <- function(t,x){digamma(gamma(a*t*(LF-LP)*b)/gamma(a*t))*(x-t)}
InnerIntegral4 <- Vectorize(function(x) { integrate(InnerFunc4, 1, x, x = x)$value})
integrate(InnerIntegral4, 30, 80)$value
```

It shows the following error:

```
Error in integrate(InnerFunc4, 1, x, x = x) : non-finite function value
```

UPDATE2:

```
InnerFunc4 <- function(t,L){digamma(gamma(a*t*(LF-LP)*b)/gamma(a*t))*(L-t)}
    
t_lower_bound = 0
t_upper_bound = 30
L_lower_bound = 30
L_upper_bound = 80
step_size = 0.5
integral = 0

t <- t_lower_bound + 0.5*step_size
while (t < t_upper_bound){
  L = L_lower_bound + 0.5*step_size
  while (L < L_upper_bound){
    volume = InnerFunc4(t,L)*step_size**2
    integral = integral + volume
    L = L + step_size
  }
  t = t + step_size
}
```

Comment: You could calculate the derivative with the help of the digamma function.

Comment: Hmm.. there's a problem with gamma at 0. Are you sure this integral converges?

Comment: What if we start the lower limit with something > 0 to approximate this? Does it sound reasonable?

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent I have updated my answer with what I tried based on your answer to my previous question. Would you have done something like this?

Comment: what about partial integration over t?

Answer (score 0):

Since It seems that your problem is only the derivative, you can get rid of it by means of partial integration:

[image]

**Edit**
Not applicable solution for lower integration bound 0.

Comment: Well seen. But **Gamma** is `NaN` at 0.

Comment: o boy, i did not think of that, but thats maybe the error that he is getting,i will trow it on matematica

Comment: @Indiano The error is also showing when I changed the lower interval a bit greater than 0.

Comment: Okay , divergnce of the integrel over an interval [0,l] l>0 seems to be strongly dependent on the parameters a,b,F,P.

Comment: If the lower bound >0 the the portial integration holds

Comment: update: use partial integration and use a tailor expansion to evaluate at 0 ,everything converges and the math gods are happy

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Meanwhile I was trying to use numerical integration and added the code in my answer. However, it is ending up with Inf. I was wondering if it was a nonsense way of doing this. Can you give your thoughts? I am requesting both of you.

Comment: You have to make some adjustments using calculus to evaluate the function in the `dt` integral at 0, I am struggling to find time to complete the answer but I hope I can find half an hour tomorrow