# Double integral using R

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1)

n=100 
s=1.5 
xbar=18 

ll=2.9307
ul=2.9768


fun = function(w) { 
  d=w^((n/2)-1)
  e=(t-xbar-(((n-1)*s^2)/(2*w)))^2
  g=n/((n-1)*s^2)
  h=(e*g+1)*w
  
  d*exp(-h/2)
}

Int_w = Vectorize(function(t) { integrate(fun, 0, Inf)$value })
integrate(Int_w , ll, ul)

#> Error in t - xbar : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am trying to perform a double integral in R. *fun* is my function here. *w* and *t* are my variables. Integrations are done in the order: *dw*, *dt*. Why am I getting the error at the end (last line of the posted code above)?

Comment: `t` is not defined in the function nor outside it. The inner integral's function argument is `w` not `t`. Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189512/double-integral-in-r)?

Comment: Int_w is the function of t, isn't it?

Comment: No, it is not, it's a function of `w`. When I changed the `t` in Vectorize to `w` and the same in the function there's no error, I got `6.438021e-61 with absolute error < 7.1e-75`.

Comment: May I see your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with package [`cubature`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cubature), that has functions for multidimensional integration over hypercubes. Note that the integrand is a function of one variable, in this case a 2-dim vector.

```r
library(cubature)

fun <- function(x) {
  t <- x[1]   # outer integral
  w <- x[2]   # inner integral
  d <- w^((n/2)-1)
  e <- (t - xbar - (((n - 1)*s^2)/(2*w)))^2
  g <- n/((n - 1)*s^2)
  h <- (e*g + 1)*w
  d*exp(-h/2)
}

n <- 100 
s <- 1.5 
xbar <- 18 

ll <- 2.9307
ul <- 2.9768

hcubature(fun, c(ll, 0), c(ul, Inf))
#> $integral
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $functionEvaluations
#> [1] 85
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0

pcubature(fun, c(ll, 0), c(ul, Inf))
#> $integral
#> [1] NaN
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $functionEvaluations
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: No. The function *fun* has two variables *w* and *t*. How can you write the function in terms of *w* only? You just can not replace *t* with *w*.

Comment: @Dihan OK, but then, you only have one value of each `ll` and `ul`. They are the limits of what integral, the inner or the outer one? And the other integral?

Comment: outer integral limits are **ll** and **ul**. 0 and *Inf* are the limits for inner integrals.

Comment: @Dihan Done, see now.