# Double integral using R program (double precision)

Tags: r

[image]

I am trying to find this integral in **R**. But I am getting 0 because the constant part is close to 0 (but not zero). How can I solve this problem without getting the final answer of 0? Please see the code I tried. None of them is working.

```
set.seed(1)
options(digits = 16)

M=1000 #Replicate
n=100 #sample size
s=1.5 # sample standard deviation
xbar=18 # sample mean
alpha=0.05 # significance level
observed_values<- function(xbar,s,n,M,alpha) {
  r=list()
  for (i in 1:M){
    Z=rnorm(1,0,1)
    U=sqrt(rchisq(1,df=n-1))
    r[[i]]=xbar+(Z*sqrt(n-1)/U)*(s/sqrt(n))+.5*((n-1)*s^2)/(U^2)
    
  }
  r2=sort(unlist(r)) 
  quantile(r2,na.rm = T,probs = c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2))
}

values1=observed_values(xbar,s,n,M,alpha)

values2=log(observed_values(xbar,s,n,M,alpha))
> values2
# 2.5%             97.5%
#   2.930742746832908 2.976810026452883

#### Integration

fun0 = function(w,t,xbar,s,n,ll,ul){
  (sqrt(n)/(sqrt(2*pi)*gamma((n-1)/2)*2^((n-1)/2)*s*sqrt(n-1)))*(w^((n/2)-1))*
    exp(-((((t-xbar-(((n-1)*s^2)/(2*w)))^2)*(n/((n-1)*s^2))+1)*w/2))
}
fun01 <- function(xbar,s,n,ll,ul) {
  integrate(function(w) { 
    sapply(w, function(w) {
      integrate(function(t) fun0(w,t,xbar,s,n,ll,ul),0,Inf)$value
    })
  }, ll, ul)$value
}

fun01(xbar,s,n,values2[1],values2[2])
# [1] 8.352234203850945e-190

fun0 = function(w){
  (sqrt(n)/(sqrt(2*pi)*gamma((n-1)/2)*2^((n-1)/2)*s*sqrt(n-1)))*(w[2]^((n/2)-1))*
    exp(-((((w[1]-xbar-(((n-1)*s^2)/(2*w[2])))^2)*(n/((n-1)*s^2))+1)*w[2]/2))
}

pcubature(fun0, c( 0, ll), c(Inf, ul))

$integral
[1] 0

$error
[1] 0

$functionEvaluations
[1] 9

$returnCode
[1] 0

> hcubature(fun0, c( 0, ll), c(Inf, ul))
$integral
[1] 0

$error
[1] 0

$functionEvaluations
[1] 85

$returnCode
[1] 0
```

Do I need to use double precision? Or can anyone suggest any other methods?

Comment: This question is a better version of your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73594014/double-integral-using-r/). But I am not understanding, in R floating-point numbers are doubles, run `typeof(1)` and `typeof(1L)` or see [`numeric`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/numeric.html). If your double integral code gives `8.352234203850945e-190`, why not accept this result as valid?

Comment: I don't think the answer I got is correct. Is there any other way to solve this problem? any suggestions?

Comment: I have coded a solution with package [Rmpfr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Rmpfr) and the solution is so close to 0 it doesn't make sense to not consider it zero.