# integrating a function with multiple variables

Tags: r, function, integral, numerical-integration

I am new to R and need some help using integration.
I have a function defined as:

```
a <- function(t) { exp(-r1*t) }
```

I have another function which uses this function and is defined as:

```
b <- function(t,x) { a(t-x)* exp(-(1-exp(-r2*x))) }
```

where, `r1` and `r2` are constants.

Now, I need to integrate the function `b(t,x)` for values of `x` that range from `0` to `t`; given that `x <= t`.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. I tried the following, but I am not sure how to tell R to integrate over 'x' and not 't'.

```
c <- integrate(b, lower=0, upper=10)
```

When i run this, I get an error saying:

> Error in a(t -x) : argument "t" is missing, with no default

Thanks in advance,
-S

Comment: What is `Nd_theta()` and in your b function one `)` is lacking

Comment: did you check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913603/calculating-double-integrals-in-r-quickly

Comment: @Ravi Sorry for a clumsy post. I had modified the equations and object names for convenience in understanding. I have now edited the question. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @user5249203 Thanks! it might help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `r1 = r2 = 1` as an example.

Since you want a **double integral**:

```
\int_{t=0}^{t=10} \int_{x=0}^{x=t} b(x,t)
```

the most basic approach is to apply `integrate()` twice.

First, you need to define a **vectorized function** evaluating the inner integral:

```
z <- function(t) sapply(t, function (t_i) integrate(b, lower = 0, upper = t_i, t = t_i)$value)
```

We can check that:

```
z(1:3)
# [1] 0.4225104 0.4440731 0.4150334
```

Now, we apply the outer integral to `z`:

```
integrate(z, lower = 0, upper = 10)
# 3.795567 with absolute error < 6.2e-06
```

My answer just aims to give you starting point. The linked post: [calculating double integrals in R quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8913603/4891738) gives you better approach for doing double integral.

Comment: Hey thanks fr the answer. It solved the problem but I am not understanding why you used t_i?

Comment: Oh is it just the placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I allways wouldn't use parameters in a function that aren't parsed to it if not really necessary. So I would write `a <- function(t, r1) { exp(-r1*t) }` and `b <- function(t, x, r2) { a(t-x)* exp(-(1-exp(-r2*x))) }` (there was also a closing bracket missing).
Second Thing, I wouldn't name results (and other objects) `c` as this is already a function name in R.
Third thing, your question didn't say what `Nd_theta` is, so I assume it is `b`.
Forth thing, you parse the function `Nd_theta` to `integrate` and not ist result `Nd_theta(...)`. Related next thing: the error message doesn't occur because of `integrate`, but because `Nd_theta` needs two arguments (presumably `x` and `t`) to work and you don't specify them when just coding `Nd_theta()`. You can check this, by only typing `Nd_theta()` into the console.

Regarding your actual question: you can specifiy additional parameters in the following way:

```
r1 <- 1
r2 <- 1
Nd_theta <- b
integrate(Nd_theta, lower = 0, upper = 10, x = 5)
```

But notice what the help page to `?integrate` says: the *first* argument of `Nd_theta` will be used for Integration. so you might need to change the defintion from `b <- function(t, x){...}` to `b <- function(x, t){...}`.